JavaFX Error: 'Exception in Application start method' Despite Correct URL in Eclipse 2024-03
I'm a beginner in JavaFX and I'm encountering a recurring issue despite trying several suggested solutions. I thought upgrading to Eclipse 2024-03 (4.31.0) might resolve my problem, but it persists. Below are my Main.java and Test.fxml codes:
Main.java :
package application;

import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.fxml.*;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("/Test.fxml"));
        if (loader.getLocation() == null) {
            System.out.println("Failed to load FXML");
            return;
        }
        Parent root = loader.load();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.setTitle("Account");
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.show();
    }
}

Test.fxml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.scene.text.*?>

<GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    alignement="center" hgap="10" vgap="10"
    >

    <Label text="Name:" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
    <TextFiels GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
    <Label text="Balance" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
    <TextFiels GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>

</GridPane>

Despite confirming the correct URL, I'm still facing the following issue:
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.3/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.3/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1085)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.3/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:893)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.3/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: GridPane is not a valid type.
/C:/Users/edgar/eclipse-workspace-2024/BankAccount/bin/Test.fxml

    at javafx.fxml@21.0.3/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2718)
    at javafx.fxml@21.0.3/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.createElement(FXMLLoader.java:2920)
    at javafx.fxml@21.0.3/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2850)
    at javafx.fxml@21.0.3/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2649)
    at javafx.fxml@21.0.3/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2563)
    at javafx.fxml@21.0.3/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2531)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:20)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.3/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.3/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.3/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.3/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.3/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.3/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.3/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application application.Main

I would appreciate any insights or solutions to help resolve this error. Thank you in advance!

I see these in your exception's stack trace: (1) Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: GridPane is not a valid type, (2) at application.Main.start(Main.java:20) - what is this line number 20 in Main.java.

Here is a similar question and an answer: javafx.fxml.LoadException: StackPane is not a valid type

The Error
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: GridPane is not a valid type.
/C:/Users/edgar/eclipse-workspace-2024/BankAccount/bin/Test.fxml

Means the FXMLLoader encountered a type in the FXML file that it cannot find the class of. Given the type in this case is a standard JavaFX class (GridPane), you most likely have the wrong or missing imports in your FXML file. And it turns out that is indeed the problem here.
Instead of:
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.scene.text.*?>

It should be:
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<!-- Note 'javafx' in the following imports instead of 'java' -->
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>


Additional Issues
There are syntax errors and misspellings:
alignement -> alignment 
TextFiels -> TextField

And unnecessary imports that aren't used:
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.scene.text.*?>

Similar layout generated in Scene Builder (slightly modified by hand to remove unnecessary row and column constraints).
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<GridPane alignment="CENTER" hgap="10.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" vgap="10.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19">
   <children>
      <Label text="Name" />
      <Label text="Balance" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
      <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
   </children>
</GridPane>


Scene Builder
Writing FXML files by hand can be tedious and error prone, especially since IDE support tends to be somewhat lacking. I recommend using Scene Builder for creating FXML files. That link is to Gluon's page for downloading Scene Builder. As of writing this answer the latest version available on the download page is 21. However, it looks like version 22 has a release on GitHub.

I edited the answer to address a couple of issues, which seemed better than adding another answer.  Feel free to make any changes to my edits you prefer.

Thanks for your help, there was actually another mistake in the syntax of my code. It works now. I'll use Scene Builder for my next FXML files.

@jewelsea Looks good to me. Just edited the format of the answer a bit.

@EdgarChauve FYI, it is perfectly acceptable and reasonable to code your JavaFX interface content by hand. To do so, write Java code calling the classes and methods in the JavaFX/OpenJFX framework rather than writing out FXML  by hand.
